# Error in XML parsing PHP

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I am processing XML file and constantly getting blow error.

```
[03-Nov-2013 19:00:27 UTC] PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 83: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: a line 79 and h1 in /home/ihklm/public_html/mydir/xml_theme.php on line 98
[03-Nov-2013 19:00:27 UTC] PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): &lt;/h1&gt;               in /home/ihklm/public_html/mydir/xml_theme.php on line 98
[03-Nov-2013 19:00:27 UTC] PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct():      ^ in /home/ihklm/public_html/mydir/xml_theme.php on line 98
[03-Nov-2013 19:00:27 UTC] PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 152: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: hr line 145 and ul in /home/ihklm/public_html/mydir/xml_theme.php on line 98
[03-Nov-2013 19:00:27 UTC] PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct():       &lt;/ul&gt; in /home/ihklm/public_html/mydir/xml_theme.php on line 98
[03-Nov-2013 19:00:27 UTC] PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct():            ^ in
```

I tried various things but no luck below is my PHP code

```
$body = $h->get();    
// echo $body;
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($body);
```

Could anyone please share some info on how i can fix this.

Thank you in advance.

Regards,
Mona

Comment: Try adding: `$body = html_entity_decode( $h->get());`

Comment: The errors are not down to your PHP code, but down to the data you are trying to parse not being valid XML. It looks like you are actually trying to parse HTML which is not, in general, valid XML. You will need a parser designed for that, such as [`DOMDocument::loadHTML`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) or [simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Hi IMSoP, Thank you for reply.. can i correct this data like using replace or something like that..